# Issue while creating an SSRS Report (RDL File), where input data is output of stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services, rdl, msbi

I'm facing an issue while creating an SSRS Report (RDL File), My requirement is like this. There is a stored procedure "xyz" which returns some data, I need to insert this data into a temp table later I need to apply few functionality over the temp table to get my final output. Please suggest.

Comment: Can't you achieve your requirement within stored procedure and generate the required result?

Comment: Please describe what is done with the the temp table data to get to 'final output'.